# gvisBubbleChart colorAxis Option via Shiny not working

Tags: r, shiny, bubble-chart, googlevis

I'm trying to declare the colorAxis and let a series of computed "Scores" define the gradient for coloring the bubbles. The visualization just keeps giving me random colors, all with the "OutlierScore" next to them on an ugly legend to the right of the plot. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong as my options list matches all of the demo codes I find. I'm using the final `gvisBubbleChart` statement as the output to my `renderGvis` code in `server.R`.

Here's some sample data:

```
                      Attribute CloseRate Quotes OutlierScore  Size
              AdvancedShopper:N     0.261   3411       292.47 1.016
              AdvancedShopper:Y     0.119  10421       259.68 2.283
                PriorCarrier:HP     0.277   1876       186.46 0.739
                     Vehicles:1     0.183   8784       179.98 1.988
                     Vehicles:2     0.106   3471       121.81 1.027
                  LeadType:Cold     0.104   3177       117.09 0.974
                      SPINOFF:Y     0.414    510       115.65 0.492
                  LeadType:Warm     0.223   2184       115.47 0.795
        MULTI_CAR_DSCNT_FLG:HMC     0.303    879       107.88 0.559
         MULTI_CAR_DSCNT_FLG:MC     0.111   3451       105.75 1.024
                PRI_CARR_NME:HP     0.253   1287       100.58 0.633
             PriorCarrier:GEICO     0.099   2476        99.74 0.847
PriorCarrier:No Prior Insurance     0.304    802        99.61 0.545
PRI_CARR_NME:No Prior Insurance     0.304    802        99.61 0.545
                    FR_BAND:P-R     0.112   3227        98.15 0.983
                  PIP_DED:2,500     0.197   3053        95.11 0.952
        AgencyName:South Agency     0.213   2120        94.81 0.783
RSrc:SPIN-OFF Additional Policy     0.434    373        91.99 0.467
             CompanionType:None     0.141  11332        87.60 2.448
                       D2V:D1V1     0.175   5830        85.67 1.454
```

Here's my gvisBubbleChart declaration.

```
YLim = c(0,max(GData$Quotes)*1.05)
XLim = c(0,max(GData$CloseRate)*1.01)
gvisBubbleChart(GData, idvar="Attribute", xvar="CloseRate", yvar="Quotes", colorvar="OutlierScore", sizevar="Size",
                options=list(title="One-Way Bubble Chart",
                             hAxis=paste("{title: 'Close Rate', minValue:0, maxValue:",XLim[2],"}",sep=""),
                             vAxis=paste("{title: 'Quotes', minValue:0, maxValue:",YLim[2],"}",sep=""),
                             width=1400, height=600, colorAxis="{minValue: 0, colors: ['red', 'green']}",
                             sizeAxis = '{minValue: 0,  maxSize: 10}',
                             bubble="{textStyle:{color: 'none'}}"))
```